# FXML Image Transparency

Tags: java, image, javafx, transparency, fxml

I am trying to accomplish two goals.

1. Have the image transparent in regards to the text.
2. Not have the image squish the text to the right.

   ```
     <Button fx:id="btn" layoutX="90.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="97.0" prefWidth="320.0" styleClass="root" text="Button">
       <graphic>
           <ImageView fitHeight="87.0" fitWidth="244.0">
               <image>
                   <Image url="@image.jpg"/>
               </image>
           </ImageView>
       </graphic>
   </Button>
   ```

Any help is appreciated greatly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340269/styling-a-javafx-2-button-using-fxml-only-how-to-add-an-image-to-a-button

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34852751/button-with-image-styling-with-fxml-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set [the `contentDisplay` property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#contentDisplayProperty) to `ContentDisplay.CENTER`. This should draw the text on top of the `graphic` used with the `Button`:

```xml
<Button fx:id="btn" contentDisplay="CENTER" ...>
    ...
</Button>
```

Comment: This works, but is there anyway to fade out the image using fxml?

Comment: @FamousFrik Fade out like setting the opacity or using a appropriate `ColorAdjust` effect???

Comment: This is a good working point and partial answer. Is there a way to just draw the image to the back, without necessarily making the text move, in this example to the center? So image in back to left, with text in center or right?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is make the Stage transparent so that everything on it would be transparent using this method: `stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT)` Then you could set the scene to transparent as well `scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT).` Approve this answer if this solved your issues:)

Comment: Thanks, but I used Scene Builder, so I am trying to keep the code in FXML. Tried this to no avail. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: So do you just want the image to be a background in your application?

Comment: behind the text, but not necessarily the whole background if that makes sense

Comment: pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" helps. Are there any FXML atrributes that affect indentation and transparency?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Your best bet is to just set the background of the GUI to the image, then put text fields and stuff on that image.